# Problem with returning a value when working with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a problem:
I have an activity and a class. The class makes a request over the network and returns the result. The activity has an object of this class, through this object the activity accesses the class and returns information. I attach pieces of code on the topic:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var dataProcessing : DataProcessing
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 dataProcessing = DataProcessing()
private fun showData(){
// other code
dataList = dataProcessing.sendRequest(townName) // return null!
val wheather = dataList.get("nameTown")
     Log.d("Egor","two $wheather")
         val tem = dataList.get("temperature")
     Log.d("Egor","three $tem")
         dataShow(wheather, tem)
 
class DataProcessing {
    private val retrofitImpl: RetrofitImpl = RetrofitImpl()
    private  val mainActivity : MainActivity = MainActivity()
    lateinit var listString : MutableMap<String, String>
    var map: Map<String,String> = mapOf()
    internal fun getInfoToMainActivity(townName:String): Map<String, String>{
       sendRequest(townName)
        return listString
    }
    internal fun sendRequest(townName:String) : Map<String,String>{
 
        retrofitImpl.getRequest().showWeather(townName).enqueue(object : Callback<DateWeather> {
            var objectMainActivity = mainActivity ?: MainActivity()
            var listString= mutableMapOf<String, String>()
 
            override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<DateWeather>, response: Response<DateWeather>) {
                val dateWeather:DateWeather? = response.body()
                if (response.isSuccessful && dateWeather != null) {
                    val nameTown = dateWeather.weather.get(0).toString()
                    Log.d("Egor","nametown" + nameTown)
                    val size = nameTown.length - 1
                    listString.apply {
                        put("nameTown", nameTown.subSequence(13, size).toString())
                        put("temperature", dateWeather.main.temp!!.toInt().toString())
                        Log.d("Egor","one ${listString.get("nameTown")}")
                    }
                    map = listString.toMap()
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<DateWeather>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity(), "network error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
        Log.d("Egor","step before returning the mep $map")
        return  listString;
    }
    }
```

By time, the logs showed the following:

```
2021-05-30 02:59:31.208 19871-19871/com.example.wheatherprog D/Egor:step before returning the map
2021-05-30 02:59:31.208 19871-19871/com.example.wheatherprog D/Egor: two null
2021-05-30 02:59:31.208 19871-19871/com.example.wheatherprog D/Egor: three null
2021-05-30 02:59:31.355 19871-19871/com.example.wheatherprog D/Egor: nametownWeather(main=Clear)
2021-05-30 02:59:31.355 19871-19871/com.example.wheatherprog D/Egor: one Clear
```

onResponse () works asynchronously, so data is written to Map ( var listString) after the program has passed the listString to the activity. As a result, I have no data, the program is empty. Calling onResponse() directly is pointless, because it doesn't return anything.
I don't want to move the code that is in Data Processing to activiti. But how do I make a request from the activity to DataProcessing and return the data from there?

I really hope for help.

Comment: I'm quite confuse with your code. can you fix them, put it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an interface which helps to act as a sort of callback. Your logical assumption is correct that since it is Async it returns after a while and till then the data is already gone back to your activity.

So here is what you can do. Create an interface.

```kotlin
interface DataProcessingCallback {
        fun onSuccessfulDataProcessed(result: Map<String,String>)
    }
```

Next we implement this interface in your activity which is the place where the callback will be received

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DataProcessingCallback {
        override fun onSuccessfulDataProcessed(result: Map<String, String>) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Third we pass on this interface to your data processing class so it can call it and get a callback in your activity

```kotlin
internal fun sendRequest(townName:String, dataProcessingCallback: DataProcessingCallback){
        // Stuff

        override fun onResponse(call: retrofit2.Call<DateWeather>, response: Response<DateWeather>) {
            val dateWeather:DateWeather? = response.body()
            if (response.isSuccessful && dateWeather != null) {
               // Stuff
                map = listString.toMap()
                dataProcessingCallback.onSuccessfulDataProcessed(map)   // Pass back to the callback
            } else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't try this option right now, but I have a concern. I tried something similar before, but I got the problem that the variables initialized in onCreate() on the callback of the return exception that the variables are not initialized. If I call onSuccessfulDataProcessed () to the View will they lag behind initialized? And do I understand correctly that i need to send the MainActivity object to sendrequest()?

Comment: @Egor0702 I might be misunderstanding you but there is no lag as such, the only lag if it is lag is the time taken for you to hit the api and get response which is normal for any app. Most apps usually show loaders.

Yes you need your callback implementation to the sendRequest object which will be as follows `dataList.get("nameTown", this)` where this implies the activity and since you have implemented the interface in your activity, it means your activity is the place to receive callback.